# Constructor is making my code ugly, and making me input irrelevant code , JAVA

Tags: java, constructor

the "blah","blah",1,1  is irrelevant since i dont get to use it
i just inputted some random string and int because java asks me to do so
because of the constructor Pokemon().
btw in this task, we we're not allowed to use static
and i needed to do this so i can use "fight"method because i needed to make an instance.
i also tried just using a random already-created object like
party[0].fight(team1,team2); but its uglier and looks more irrelevant.

```
package pokemon;
import java.util.Random;


public class PokemonMain {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Pokemon[] party = new Pokemon[6];
        Pokemon[] party2 = new Pokemon[6];
        party[0] = new Pokemon("pikachu", "electric", 500, 1);
        party[1] = new Pokemon("raichu", "electric", 500, 1);
        party[2] = new Pokemon("charmander", "water", 500, 1);
        party[3] = new Pokemon("magikarp", "electric", 500, 1);
        party[4] = new Pokemon("bulbasaur", "electric", 500, 1);
        party[5] = new Pokemon("kabuto", "electric", 500, 1);

        party2[0] = new Pokemon("pikachu2", "electric", 500, 1);
        party2[1] = new Pokemon("raichu2", "electric", 500, 1);
        party2[2] = new Pokemon("charmander2", "water", 500, 1);
        party2[3] = new Pokemon("magikarp2", "electric", 500, 1);
        party2[4] = new Pokemon("bulbasaur2", "electric", 500, 1);
        party2[5] = new Pokemon("kabuto2", "electric", 500, 1);

        //Picks random pockemons given an array of pokemons
        Random randomGenerator = new Random(); 
        int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(6);
        Pokemon team1 = party[randomInt];
        randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(6);
        Pokemon team2 = party2[randomInt];

        Pokemon forTheSakeOfTheMethod = new Pokemon("blah","blah",1,1);
        //the "blah","blah",1,1  is irrelevant since i dont get to use it
        // i just inputted some random string and int because java asks me to do so
        //because of the constructor Pokemon().
        //btw in this task, we we're not allowed to use static
        //and i needed to do this so i can use "fight"method because i needed to make
          an
        //instance.
        // i also tried just using a random already-created object like
        // party[0].fight(team1,team2); but its uglier and looks more irrelevant.
        forTheSakeOfTheMethod.fight(team1,team2);

======================================================================
package pokemon;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Pokemon {
    private String name;
    private String type;
    private int hp, exp, atk, def, xdef, xatk, spd, level;
    public static String region ="Kanto";
    public int generation;
    public int[] hello = new int[5];


    private static int numberOfPokemons = 0;

    public Pokemon(String name, String type, int hp, int level){
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.hp = hp;
        this.level = level;
    }

    public void fight(*parameters*){
        //something
    }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You're posting a fact.

Comment: I agree that your code is ugly. However your post doesn't contain question.

Comment: being that the code is (presumably) in working condition, this is better suited for code review as opposed to stack overflow.

Comment: Just put in a default constructor if you want an empty pokemon, or make fight a static method outside the class.

Comment: The question is, are there any other methods to call the nonstatic 'fight' method that doesn't make me input irrelevant code like "blah","blah",1,1 ? i can easily call it if it's static but we're not allowed to make it static for this code.

Comment: Then the method signature should be `public void fight(Pokemon team2)`, if you're not allowed to do it in a static way!

Answer (score 3):

Your quick fix is to add a no-arg constructor (as per @Grammin) however i personally think what you probably want to do is change the 'fight' method to only have a single parameter. e.g.

```
public class Pokemon
{
  ...
  public int fight(Pokemon team2) {
    Pokemon team1 = this;
    ...
    return winner;
  }
}
```

You could then use this like so:

```
team1.fight(team2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either change the Pokemon class/constructor, or you create another class which handles the fighting.

```
public class PokemonFightManager
{
   public int fight(Pokemon pokemon1, Pokemon pokemon2)
   {
       //do something and return result
   }

   public int fightTeam(Pokemon[] team1, Pokemon[] team2)
   {
       //do something and return result
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could make another constructor in Pokemon that doesn't take any arguments:

```
public class Pokemon {
  public Pokemon(){}
}
```

But I suspect that you need your name/type/hp/level for the fight method if it was provided to you like that.